# Shilov on calculating Vandermonde determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

From [Shilov's Linear Algebra, Pg 15](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=5U6loPxlvQkC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=shilov%20vandermonde%20determinant&source=bl&ots=bdRlerxuwa&sig=b23HdaAFIsJHusu0PIOGdPpTd8Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PAWpVIGlMM2XuAT5zYJ4&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=shilov%20vandermonde%20determinant&f=false) , he shows how one would calculate the *Vandermonde determinant* by treating is as a polynomial. My question which theorem do he mean by mentioning "by a familiar theorem of elementary algebra"? I am aware of the remainder theorem, but I think this is not what he is getting at. Can someone tell me (1)which theorem is he referring to (2) and explain to me how is he using it to calculate the determinant? Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can somebody explain to me how the author is then calculating the determinant based on his method of using polynomials?

Answer (score 1):

The theorem of elementary algebra in question is that if a polynomial function $f(x)$ vanishes at $a$, so that $f(a)=0$, then $f$ is divisible by $x-a$. The author is using this to show that the determinant is divisible by a certain polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Could somebody explain why in this [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant/Proof_3)

they got as C coefficient of the polynomial

$P \left({x}\right) = C \left({x - x_1}\right) \left({x - x_2}\right) \dotsm \left({x - x_{n-1} }\right)$

the leading coefficient (with $x^{n-1}$ power) in the expansion of the determinant by the last row?

....

Perform row expansion by the last row.

Then $P \left({x}\right)$ is seen to be a polynomial of degree $n-1$:

$P \left({x}\right) = \begin{vmatrix}
  x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-2} & x_1^{n-1} \\
  x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-2} & x_2^{n-1} \\
  x_3 & x_3^2 & \cdots & x_3^{n-2} & x_3^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2 & \cdots & x_{n-1}^{n-2} & x_{n-1}^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix} + 
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-2} & x_1^{n-1} \\
  1 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-2} & x_2^{n-1} \\
  1 & x_3^2 & \cdots & x_3^{n-2} & x_3^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_{n-1}^2 & \cdots & x_{n-1}^{n-2} & x_{n-1}^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}x \ \ + \ \ \cdots \ \ + \ \
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-2} \\
  1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-2} \\
  1 & x_3 & x_3^2 & \cdots & x_3^{n-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2 & \cdots & x_{n-1}^{n-2}
\end{vmatrix}x^{n-1}$.

By the [Polynomial Factor Theorem](/wiki/Polynomial_Factor_Theorem):

$P \left({x}\right) = C \left({x - x_1}\right) \left({x - x_2}\right) \dotsm \left({x - x_{n-1} }\right)$

where $C$ is the leading coefficient (with $x^{n-1}$ power).

Thus:

$P \left({x}\right) = V_{n-1} \left({x - x_1}\right) \left({x - x_2}\right) \dotsm \left({x - x_{n-1} }\right)$

which by evaluating at $x = x_n$ gives:

$V_n = V_{n-1} \left({x_n - x_1}\right) \left({x_n - x_2}\right) \dotsm \left({x_n - x_{n-1} }\right)$